# I installed MAAS server, would like to add one node with a different ubuntu release, how should I do it?

Tags: server, juju, maas

I looked around, it seems lots of information, is there a step by step instruction somewhere? I tried to add a VM-node manually,it is in commissioning state, what should I prepare before starting using juju? Everywhere the example is with 10.x.x.x, guess that ip address should be based on my own network.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your manually added VM is configured properly, as described [here](http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/configure.html#choosing-a-series-to-install). You can choose the Ubuntu release from the drop down menu. I'm assuming you followed the installation instructions outlined [here](http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/install.html), especially the [Post-Install Tasks](http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/install.html#post-install-tasks), like **importing the boot images**. They are needed, along with correct DHCP configuration on the network, so that VMs can be discovered and PXE boot.

If the VM still stays *Commissioning*, the [Troubleshooting](http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/troubleshooting.html#nodes-hang-on-commissioning) section might help.